# Page resizing in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, resize

We are working with two brochures, which we are looking to copy content from into one new brochure. These two brochures are different page sizes, and so image and text are different sizes as well.

What we would like to do is resize the pages of either brochure and copy them into the new brochure, keeping all the text and images in the same position and in tact (except smaller or bigger).

How would we go about doing this? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, this can't be done as an automated process, and if it can, I'm not sure you should anyway.

Often with different mediums/page-sizes, the actual design considerations will change, small text size will adjust and images may become too small for visible detail.

Simply resizing the page will often lose some design information.

You may want to resize the pages, then actually take each page/spread into it's own consideration and try to adjust, or reorganise the layout to suit the new page size.

You're looking for a quick fix, but I think you should treat a resize as a design project by itself, just to ensure you're satisfying all parties involved.